# Unable to get integer number as text via xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am unable to get integer number as text from .xls file via xlrd. I have the following data in my cell:

```
20
```

and the cell type in Excel is "Text"

Also I have the following code to read this value:

```
some_value = sheet.cell(row, column).value.encode('utf8')
```

But it gives me

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'

`sheet.cell(row, column).ctype` returns 1. According to the [documentation](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Cell-class), it means "a Unicode string"

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like it should work. You probably need to give us more information. (Less verbiage; more cut-and-paste from actual code, actual interactive sessions, and actual tracebacks.)

Comment: Works fine for me also, ctype returns 1 and the  encoding works doing it as per your example. Only time I got an error was before I changed the cell type to Text.

Comment: Voted down for not writing what you ended up doing to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just

```
some_value = sheet.cell(row, column)
```

That's what I have in my code, anything that can be converted to int, float gets automatically converted. Others are left as strings.